# Can’t screw over the range microwave into overhead cabinet because there are already cupboard screws there!

Tags: installation

We purchased a new over the range microwave and we were hopeful the bracket and cupboard holes would line up. No such luck.

New bracket is up on the wall successfully but the screw holes to mount it from the above cabinet line up exaclty with the camlocks on the underside of the cupboard so we have no place to drill the holes to attach the top of the microwave. Same on both sides. What stupid luck!

We can’t lower the microwave anymore than it already is so adding another wood piece to screw into isn’t an option.

So frustrated! Hoping you have a good idea for a quick and easy fix!

[image]

Comment: What does this mean "from the actually cupboard"? It's not clear what is in the way of where you want the bolt holes.

Comment: Hard to explain - the cupboard camlocks are in the way - exactly where I need to drill a hold to screw top of microwave.

Comment: Take a picture and post it.

Comment: Can you post another picture from further away

Comment: Alternately, return that OTR and get one that uses a different mounting pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The camlocks can be turned and will come out.

Drill past the post that is in the camlock hole. The bolt attachments for the micro usually have some movement, "wiggle room" so you can still get the bolts lined up.

The posts that the cams locked on will hold the bottom. To be safe, add an "L" bracket inside the cabinet on each side to help support the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Get a cheap pocket hole jig. Break off the bracket designed for laying out the jig's offset, and clamp it below the shelf to drill pocket holes. Install a couple pocket screws in this manner in the neighborhood of the offensive cam. Now drill through the cam for your microwave hardware. Usually the cams are a soft zinc alloy, so it should be easy if you miss the bolt head.